# Informatica cloud (IOD) error codes

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

can someone please share how can I get the error codes which can cause session failure to a Informatica cloud job or please share any document/website for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on StackOverFlow! Please add more context to your question, otherwise no-one will be able to help you

Comment: I am building a code, that can read from session log if it has any error codes or not(only those which can cause session failure). Need to utilize this code further in my project for some service work. Looking forward if I can get some information from here

Answer (score 1):

You can use the activityLog REST API to get the error messages related to the task if it has failed. You can take a look at the developer guide here:
https://network.informatica.com/docs/DOC-15641

Alos, you can parse the session log available after the task run to look for error messages and codes.